# How to make a tex-like typesetting engine

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, markup, s-expression, typesetting

Because of the complexity of (LaTex), I recently think of a idea that using a scheme (or S-expression) like language to make a article/book/etc, and make a typesetting engine that can convert the format to pdf.
However, which of the library should I used? I have found pango and cairo, but I doubt whether it is suitable, or should I create one from zero? Is there any references that I can use ?[eg. https://github.com/bramstein/typeset ]

Comment: you could start by converting/transforming your language to LaTex or xsl-fo and let latex or [Apache fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop) produce the actual pdf

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, but I just think of the solutions on making a pdf-rendering typesetting engine.